# CloudWatch log group is not deleted on cdk destroy

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have this CDK code:

```
const logGroup = new LogGroup(this, 'MyAppLogGroup', {
  logGroupName: 'myapp',
  retention: RetentionDays.ONE_DAY
});
```

When I run `cdk deploy`, log group is created in CloudWatch, but when I run `cdk destroy`, it's not deleted. Is there some way to enable this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-logs.LogGroup.html#removalpolicy. You need to set the `removalPolicy` of the `LogGroup` to `DESTROY` as the default one is `RETAIN`

Answer (score 7):

Milan is 100% correct here, I'm just adding some example and more details about how to do it..

```js
import { RemovalPolicy } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { LogGroup, RetentionDays } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-logs";


const accessLogGroup = new LogGroup(this, 'MyAppLogGroup', {
    logGroupName: 'myapp',
    retention: RetentionDays.ONE_DAY,
    // This does the work:
    removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
});
```

Comment: just quick nitpicking. Isn't it supposed to be `cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY` instead of `core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY`? Since you import the core as cdk.