# How to delete lambda function log group on CDK destroy using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

Currently, I am trying to delete a log group from a lambda function that's created by AWS CDK

Here is what my stack currently looks like:

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_lambda
)
from aws_cdk.aws_logs import CfnLogGroup, LogGroup
from datetime import datetime
f = """
import json
from datetime import datetime

def handler(event, context):
    print(f'test {datetime.now()}')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(f'test {datetime.now()}')
    }
"""

class CdktestStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        fn = aws_lambda.Function(self, f"AndyTest-{datetime.now()}",
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            handler="index.handler",
            code=aws_lambda.InlineCode(f)
        )

        lg = LogGroup.from_log_group_name(self, f"lambda_log_group-{datetime.now()}", fn.log_group.log_group_name)
        lg.apply_removal_policy(core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY)
```

By default, the lambda log group is retained after CDK destroy has completed.

I have tried to manage the log group by using [LogGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-logs.LogGroup.html) to manage the logs.

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967795/cloudwatch-log-group-is-not-deleted-on-cdk-destroy) for destroying a log group but it will not as this line:

```
lg = LogGroup.from_log_group_name(self, f"lambda_log_group-{datetime.now()}", fn.log_group.log_group_name)
```

returns an [ILogGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-logs.ILogGroup.html) and throws this error when I try and call

```
lg.apply_removal_policy(core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY)
```

with this error:

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot apply RemovalPolicy: no child or not a CfnResource. Apply the removal policy on the CfnResource directly.
```

My objective is to use CDK to manage the log group so that the resource can be deleted on destroy without using boto3.

Comment: Really cool.  I've been wondering if this was possible for a while, but you've gotten a lot farther than I.  I'll look into this over the course of the day.

Comment: @Hcaertnit thanks for taking a look, I did notice this [issue on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11549) so it looks like it was requested as a feature but I don't know how much further the issue got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works fine by creating a log group seperately based on name rather than loading it in from name. See below for detailed implementation:

```
from aws_cdk import core, aws_lambda
from aws_cdk.aws_logs import CfnLogGroup, LogGroup, RetentionDays
from datetime import datetime

f = """
import json
from datetime import datetime

def handler(event, context):
    print(f'test {datetime.now()}')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(f'test {datetime.now()}')
    }
"""


class CdktestStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        fn = aws_lambda.Function(
            self,
            f"AndyTest-{datetime.now()}",
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            handler="index.handler",
            code=aws_lambda.InlineCode(f),
        )

        LogGroup(
            self,
            f"lambda_log_group-{datetime.now()}",
            log_group_name=f"/aws/lambda/{fn.function_name}",
            removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            retention=RetentionDays.ONE_DAY,
        )
```

A word of warning, if you use a log_retention attribute it creates a custom resource to automatically generate an associated log group for you. So the above works fine.